# Why am I receiving wrong link in mail in Grails

Tags: email, grails, hyperlink

I have a problem with wrong link in my grails application. I am new in Grails.

menu.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="bootstrap-main" />
<title>SARNA</title>
</head>
<body>
    //other options

    <g:link class="btn btn-primary" controller="Unit" action="index">Send Mail</g:link>

</body>
</html>
```

UnitController.groovy

```
package com.sarna.controller

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator;

class UnitController {

    LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator
    def index() {
        def login = "Tazz" 
        def token = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        def link = grailsLinkGenerator.serverBaseURL
        sendMail {
            to "mygmail@gmail.com"
            subject "SARNA - account created"
            html g.render (template:"/mail/templates/test", model:[login:login, link:link])
          }
    }
}
```

_test.gsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Welcome ${login },</h3>
  <a href="${createLink(base: '${link }')}">${link }</a>
  <p>Greetings, <br/>SARNA Team</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Everytime I'm receiving mail with this link : `http://localhost:8080/SARNA`. It looks like good, but when I'm clicking it, opens new tab in my browser with this address: `https://o.iplsc.com/%24%7Blink%20%7D/unit/index`. 
Something it's wrong but I don't have any idea.. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%24%7Blink%20%7D` is the urlencoded version of `${link }`.  a) grails/groovy does not replace ${} within `'strings'`. and b) you don't need it here; just use `base: link`

if you do not want to see the controller/action in the link, you have to make sure, that your `/` maps properly to your controller and then could simply use `${createLink(absolute: true, uri: '')}` (or to play it safe `uri: '/'`)

Comment: Thanks cfrick, it works, but now I've other problem: `http://localhost:8080/SARNA/unit/index` I guess, that this is caused by action `index()` of `UnitController`. How can I receive this link : `http://localhost:8080/SARNA/`